# $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-2y=2\tan^3\left(x\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-2y=2\tan^3\left(x\right).
\end{equation}
using the method of undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters, with $y_p\left(x\right)=\tan\left(x\right)$.

---

This is what I have so far:
\begin{equation}
r^2-2=0\implies r=\pm\sqrt{2},\:\:\:\:\:\therefore\:\: C_1 e^{\sqrt{2}t}+C_2 e^{-\sqrt{2}t},
\end{equation}
so that is my "complimentary solution" but I do not know what to do with it.

Comment: @Amzoti What about $C-1$ and $C_2$? Should I say they're $v_1\left(x\right)$ and $v_2\left(x\right)$, functions, and solve for them if that is possible using variation of parameters?

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you very much! I will mark it as the correct answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1):

the homogeneous solution of your equation is
$y=C_1e^{-\sqrt{2}x}+C_2e^{\sqrt{2}x}$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. In class we've simply stated it to be our "complimentary" solution, and then we also find a "particular" solution (via <i>Fundamentals of Differential Equations</i>, Nagle et. al.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but the general solution of the nonhomogeneous equation is just the fundamental set of solutions to the homogeneous equation added to the particular solution. So you have everything, just put it all together.

Comment: How do I find a solution? I don't understand. I have $y_p\left(x\right)=\tan\left(x\right)$, but what do I do with that??

Comment: add tan(x) to the solutions you found the the homogeneous equation. Then you are done.

Comment: Okay, did that. Thanks!